# Pure virtual and override function (c++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual

I looked over the internet for an answer to my questions but couldn't find any, so here I am.

Is it correct to specify override to my function that derived from a pure virtual:

```
class baseClass
{
    public:
        virtual void myFunction() = 0;
}

class derivedClass : public baseClass
{
    public:
        virtual void myFunction() override;
}
```

Is this correct?

And my second question is:
Do I have to specify virtual in the derivedClass for my function even though no class will inherite from my derived class (it will be final)?

Thank you a lot for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this correct?

[Yes.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) Override ensures that the function is virtual and overriding a virtual function from the base class. The program is ill-formed (a compile-time error is generated) if this is not true.

> Do I have to specify virtual in the derivedClass for my function even though no class will inherite from my derived class (it will be final)?

No you don't. But even if you leave away the virtual specifier it remains virtual. Because it has been declared virtual in your `BaseClass`.

> If some member function vf is declared as virtual in a class Base, and
>   some class Derived, which is derived, directly or indirectly, from
>   Base, has a declaration for member function with the same
>
> - name
> - parameter type list (but not the return type)
> - cv-qualifiers
> - ref-qualifiers
>
> Then this function in the class Derived is also virtual (whether or
>   not the keyword virtual is used in its declaration) and overrides
>   Base::vf (whether or not the word override is used in its
>   declaration). Base::vf does not need to be visible (can be declared
>   private, or inherited using private inheritance) to be overridden.

- [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the share. One more question: why is the compiler not complaining when I do not specify the override in the derivedClass?

Comment: The override specifier has been introduced in C++11. It prevents you from mistakenly adding new functions that you think are overrides. For example if you mistakenly change the return type in your DerivedClass the compiler will come up with an error if you used the override specifier. If you're not using the override specifier you'll end up declaring a new virtual method.

Answer (score 1):

Also, please remember that you should define a virtual destructor (can be empty one) in baseClass, in order to guarantee a proper resource deallocation in the derived classes.